# AD group and permissions SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-administration

Our production server has group @supporttechnician and that is active directory(AD) group, we have 10 people in that group and I want to give 6 people more privileges than other 4, how can I go for this, I am Software Engineer, not a professional DBA.

your help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Define "more privlages"? You could grant explicit access to the objects you want them to access. If this list is long, then i'd suggest another group.

Comment: You make another group, assign the permissions you want to the new group, and move the six people to that group instead.

Comment: @scsimon I want those 4 people to only have read access rights, and rest of them can do all DML, but I don't want to create any other group for this issue

Comment: Then you'd have to remove them from the group and give them explicit read only.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you create additional groups this will more than likely cause issues in the future (essentially it'll be an additional step for starters and leavers of your organisation).
Create two additional AD groups one called something like "DBReadOnly" and another called "DBManagers". Then add the @supporttechnician group to the "DBReadOnly" group and only the 6 higher privileged staff to the "DBManagers" group. You then need to add the groups to the SQL instance security. 
Easiest way to do this is launch SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and login with a user with security rights ('sa' account for example). Then select the 'Security' folder in Object Explorer, expand 'Logins' and check that the members of staff you are adding don't already have permissions (if they do, you need to sort this first). To add the AD groups, right click 'logins' > 'New login' and enter the domain group information in the panel, then from the 'User Mappings' page section grant the permissions to each database as required.